Gscatter not showing up at all. blender 4.1

I'm using Blender 4.1 and i wanted to try gscatter for the first time. Doesn't work at all. I'm trying to scatter a asset i downloaded from the addon itself. I also tried to just scatter a default cube on a default plane, no luck. I tried to folow the official tutorial, but it just doesn't work. pls help

Since that's a third-party addon we can't really help, but are you sure that the addon has been updated to work with Blender 4.1? - Check on the web site or with the addon authors.

I just watched a tutorial a few minutes ago where someone used the Grasland assets in Geometry Nodes, because the Gscatter addon does not work in the current Blender 4.1 version. And the changelog for Gscatter clearly states the latest release only works with versions 3.5 to 4.0

thanks a lot i wass tooo worried ,and even installed blender again thank you soo muchh

Gscatter is not yet compatible with Blender 4.1. Here's the official response of Gscatter on their discord:

You can download lower Blender versions here https://download.blender.org/release/

you can download any blender version here
https://download.blender.org/release/
